# How do I get UIGestureRecognizers to work?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having trouble just turning on gesture recognizers in my code.  I added a handleTap callback to to the tap gesture recognizer but the print statement never happens.  I'm just not having any luck.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

In my ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

}

@end
```

This is what I have in my ViewController.m

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        View *myview = [[View alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];



        myview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        myview.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(handleTap)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.delegate = self;
        [myview addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        self.view = myview;
    }

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"dismiss keyboard");
    //[usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}
```

**Edit: I added a text field and when I click on the text field I see the tap selector print statement.  But if I tap off the text field I don't get the selector print statement.**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your selector. Try changing

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(handleTap)];
```

And replace it with

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

To make the selector match the signature for handleTap.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong selector when initialising.

The line should read like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

Notice the colon after `handleTap` to match the method you want to use.

Comment: I added the colon but still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked the the UIView `myView` is on top and visible?

Comment: I have only one view and it has visible buttons and text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently subclassing the UIView and overriding drawrect with an empty function caused the selector to be called.